# ERC721Enumerable totalSupply() returns 0 on rinkeby. solidity v0.8.4

Tags: solidity, erc-721, hardhat, solidity-0.8.x

I'm deploying an ERC721Enumerable token on rinkeby testnet and when I request the **totalSupply()** function (Counters doesn't work either) I get a return of 0.. even though my tokens show up on etherscan & opensea. I did notice that under my contract overview on etherscan the total supply doesn't show up either. I've been scratching my head for quite some time trying to figure this out.. any help is appreciated.

```
    function mint(uint256 _quantity) external payable {
        require(totalSupply() < MAX_SUPPLY, "SOLD OUT");
        require(totalSupply() + _quantity <= MAX_SUPPLY, "SOLD OUT");
        //require(tokenSupply.current() < MAX_SUPPLY, "SOLD OUT");
        //require(tokenSupply.current() + _quantity <= MAX_SUPPLY, "SOLD OUT");
        require(_quantity > 0, "AMOUNT CANNOT BE ZERO");
        require(_quantity <= MAX_PER_TX, "AMOUNT EXCEEDED PER TXN");
        require(msg.value == (_quantity * PRICE), "PRICE LIMIT NOT REACHED");
        for (uint256 i=0; i<=_quantity; i++) {
            uint256 currentToken = uint256(totalSupply()) + 1;
            _safeMint(msg.sender, currentToken);
            _totalClaimed[msg.sender] += 1;
            //tokenSupply.increment();
            //_safeMint(msg.sender, tokenSupply.current());
        }
    }
```

```
describe("Get Total Supply", function () {
    it("Should return total supply of tokens", async function () {
        const Eyescream = await ethers.getContractFactory("Eyescream");
        const eyescream = await Eyescream.deploy();
        await eyescream.deployed();

    //let totalAmount = await eyescream.totalSupply();
    let totalAmount = await eyescream.getSupply();
    //totalAmount +=1;
    //await totalAmount.wait();
    console.log("Total amount foobar", totalAmount)
    console.log("Total Amount: ", parseInt(totalAmount))

   })
})
```

[image]

Comment: are you overriding _beforeTokenTransfer somewhere?

Comment: @MajdTL No, I haven't added _beforeTokenTransfer.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The problem was with my tests. I had to mint some tokens before calling. lol.

```
describe("Get Total Supply", function () {
  it("Should return total supply of tokens", async function () {
    const Eyescream = await ethers.getContractFactory("Eyescream");
    const eyescream = await Eyescream.deploy();
    await eyescream.deployed();

    let quantity = 2
    txn = await eyescream.mint(quantity, { // mints 2 tokens
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther((0.08 * quantity).toString())
    });
    await txn.wait();

    console.log("Minted");

    let totalAmount = await eyescream.getSupply();
    console.log("Total amount foobar", totalAmount)
    console.log("Total Amount: ", parseInt(totalAmount))

  })
})
```